# Will using shared hosting with many other sites on the same IP address hurt SEO?

Tags: ip-address, web-hosting, name

My website shares the same IP address with a lot of other internet sites (approx 500 sites) that are not mine. How is this possible? is this affecting my SEO?

Answer (score 3):

No, it really won't affect your SEO in any way. There are many hostings using one server for many domains.

Answer (score 2):

Shared hosting uses one server for many sites and is pretty common (although I've never heard of as many as 500 on one server before).

Contrary to what others said, there is a *small* chance it could affect SEO. If the majority of the other 500 sites are spammy, pornographic, virus-ridden sites then you could be classed as being in a "[bad neighbourhood](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66356)" and devalued in search.

This is even moreso the case if you don't have your own domain name (eg `yoursite.host.com`) as the parent domain could end up being banned.

However this is rare and almost certainly nothing to worry about.

Comment: 500+ is not at all surprising to me. I have seen a server at one of those $4/yr places hosting 10k.

Answer (score 1):

You're on shared hosting, there are other sites on the same server, and the server serves different websites based on the domain name the browser requests. No, it won't affect your SEO.

Comment: "based on the domain name the browser requests." - Specifically, the domain name is passed in the `Host` HTTP request header and the web server matches this against a named virtual host.